Accessibility - nested listitem
Is it possible to make screen reader correctly read nested list items? I can't use uls and lis; I need to operate on divs.
Consider below code, I want the screen reader to read that the list contains four items, but instead it always says that list contains two elements. What do I do wrong?
<div role="list">
    <div>
        <div role="listitem"/>
        <div role="listitem"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div role="listitem"/>
        <div role="listitem"/>
    </div>
</div>

To me, it seems like role="list" always checks how many direct children it has and consider them as list items. But in such case what's the point of using role="listitem"? I was also trying to use role="group", but without success.

Why can't you use <ul> and <li> tags?

that's why you should use semantic tags rather than attributes. Besides that the role listitem must be a direct child of the role list. a listitem can contain a list.

Which screen reader?

NVDA for example

The role nesting in the code example is not correct. Assuming you want the equivalent of the following:
<ul>
  <li>Vegetables
    <ul>
      <li>Tomatoes</li>
      <li>Lettuce</li>
      <li>Broccoli</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Meat</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ul>

(Note that you can't nest an ul directly inside another ul; you always need an li element.)
Then replacing the standard list markup with div elements and role attributes, should result in the following code:
  <div role="list">
    <div role="listitem">Vegetables
      <div role="list">
        <div role="listitem">Tomatoes</div>
        <div role="listitem">Lettuce</div>
        <div role="listitem">Broccoli</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="listitem">Fruit</div>
    <div role="listitem">Meat</div>
    <div role="listitem">Bread</div>
  </div>

This means that you have never have a div without a role inside <div role="list">. In addition, you can't have a <div role="list"> directly nested inside another <div role="list">; the sublist should be inside an <div role="listitem"> just like the ul for the sublist should be inside an li.
NVDA will read this mostly the same as a regular unordered list, except for the announcement of bullet points. When it finds the sublist, it will announce that as a list of three items. Since it does not leave the outer list, it won't say "out of list" before announcing the sublist; this is the subtle cue that it begins reading a sublist instead of a new list.
